# What process uses my camera (Macbook)

Tags: macos, isight

How to detect what process uses my cam on MacOS? I get an error when I want to take a photo:

```
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x206fde0, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x206fd30
FATAL: setting data channel failed - cam busy/not connected ?
```

Comment: could you add a bit of code to show what you are doing and which line of your code does the error actually get thrown from?

Comment: Actually this is a record from system.log. I still have exact the same troubles with Skype. But my question about common way in Macos to determine application resource usage.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to admit it, but I spent quite a bit of time working on a (AFAIK) still unreleased product that was attempting to determine this same process information.

Apple makes *some* information available via the AVCaptureDevice class, such as the ["`inUseByAnotherApplication`" property](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/inUseByAnotherApplication), but I *believe* this only works if the device is being used *exclusively* by an application (and in most cases, one single camera can feed data & frames to multiple applications at a time).

This still doesn't give you what you really want, the process id(s) of the other apps  using your Macintosh camera.

And I don't think Apple is going to give that information up easily, as this bumps up against a combination of Apple's privacy and "sandbox" philosophies:  Apple wants applications to play in their own sandbox and not to be aware of anything regarding other applications.

I would recommend filing an enhancement bug with Apple at http://bugreporter.apple.com.  I've already filed one myself ( rdar://9951989 ), but the more developers who ask for this functionality, the more likely it is Apple might provide this to us in future versions of their OS.